# Closed form for Fibonacci-like recurrence with $\frac{2}{n}$ coefficient

Tags: recurrence-relations

I came across the following recurrence relation, and was wondering if there might be some way to get a closed form:

$F\left(0\right)=0$

$F\left(1\right)=1$

$F\left(n\right)=F\left(n-1\right)+\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)F\left(n-2\right)$

Comment: what is the $\left( \frac{2}{n}  \right),$  Legendre symbol?

Comment: It is just basic division. Sorry that was not clear.

Comment: Have you tried generating functions?

Comment: @AlexR. It's quite cumbersome. I tried that but I left right away.

Answer (score 2):

The DE associated with the recurrence relation
$$ n a_n = n a_{n-1} + 2 a_{n-2} \tag{1} $$
is given by
$$ x f' = xf+x^2 f'+2x^2 f \tag{2}$$
that is separable. By solving it we get that our coefficients depend on the coefficient of the Taylor series of $$g(x)=\frac{e^{-2x}}{(1-x)^3}\tag{3}$$
in a neighbourhood of zero, that can be computed by convolution. By stars and bars and the fact that $g(x)$ has a triple pole at $x=1$ we have that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ behaves like a second-degree polynomial in $n$ plus a small perturbation, so it is *way different* from the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Really fascinated by this answer. How do you know that the DE is $x f' = xf+x^2 f'+2x^2 f \tag{2}$? How do you solve it and determine that the coefficients depend on the Taylor series of $g(x)=\frac{e^{-2x}}{(1-x)^3}\tag{3}$?

Comment: @user51819: standard techniques. Have a look at Generatingfunctionology by Wilf.

Comment: This file here explains all of this? https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf

Comment: @user51819: and much more. It is a recommended lecture for anyone.

Comment: Thanks! Any other recommendations?

Comment: @user51819: another interesting book about this branch of combinatorics is Flajolet - Analytic combinatorics. It goes deeper on the theory of asymptotic expansions through the saddle point method, for instance.

Comment: So one solves the problem, gives book recommendations and still gets downvoted. Thank you, ******les.

Comment: Just for the record I upvoted you everywhere in this comment chain + the answer; so it was not me

Comment: Is it possible to expand on the fact that $F\left(n\right)$ "behaves like a second-degree polynomial" and provide a more concrete formula for it?