# What is the solution to $F\left(n\right)=F\left(n-1\right)+\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)F\left(n-2\right)$ with Legendre symbol?

Tags: recurrence-relations, legendre-symbol

The recurrence
$F\left(n\right)=F\left(n-1\right)+\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)F\left(n-2\right)
$
was proposed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879134/closed-form-for-fibonacci-like-recurrence-with-inverse-n-coefficient)

Because of the way
the question was formatted,
a commenter asked if the
$\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)
$ 
meant the Legendre symbol.
The proposer said no,
it was just ordinary division.

That made me wonder,
suppose the Legendre symbol
*was* meant.
What would the solution be?

So that is my question.

I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Not too familiar with this, but isn't Legendre symbol only defined for odd prime numbers? So it would be undefined for many values of $n$. I don't think this could work but I'm no expert

Comment: We may take $\left( \frac{2}{n} \right)$ as the Jacobi symbol, but there are still issues if $n$ is even. Besides that, it should lead to a complicated hybrid between the Cauchy and Dirichlet convolutions, with very little chances to have a nice closed form. Not that interesting.

Comment: @m1cky22 You could use the generalization (the Jacobi symbol), which is the product of Legendre symbols for each prime $p$ of $n$ (raised to the appropriate powers). According to Wolfram Alpha, for even $n$ the result is shown as $0$ but I don't know if that necessarily makes sense because the Legendre symbol is not defined for $p=2$.

Comment: One can instead use the Kronecker symbol to generalize to all integers $n$